# why is my CanCan Ability class overly permissive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

I'm (finally) wiring CanCan / Ability into my app, and I've started by writing the RSpec tests.  But they're failing — my Abilities appear to be overly permissive, and I don't understand why.

First, the Ability class.  The intention is that non-admin users can manage only themselves.  In particular, they cannot look at other users:

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new           # create guest user if needed
    if (user.has_role?(:admin))
      can(:manage, :all)
    else
      can(:manage, User, :id => user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

The RSpec tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'cancan/matchers'

describe Ability do
  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create
  end

  describe 'guest user' do
    before(:each) do
      @guest = nil
      @ability = Ability.new(@guest)
    end

    it "should_not list other users" do
      @ability.should_not be_able_to(:read, User)
    end

    it "should_not show other user" do
      @ability.should_not be_able_to(:read, @user)
    end

    it "should_not create other user" do
      @ability.should_not be_able_to(:create, User)
    end

    it "should_not update other user" do
      @ability.should_not be_able_to(:update, @user)
    end

    it "should_not destroy other user" do
      @ability.should_not be_able_to(:destroy, @user)
    end
  end
end
```

All five of these tests fail.  I've read the part of [Ryan's documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities) where he says:

> Important: If a block or hash of
>   conditions exist they will be ignored
>   when checking on a class, and it will
>   return true.

... but at most, that would only explain two of the five failures.  So clearly I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: **slap** (sound of hand slapping my own head).  My User model has validations, so in my RSpec tests, `@user = User.create` was failing as was `@admin = Admin.create`, so they had null ids.  From the perspective of the Ability class, @user and @admin were acting as guest users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this bad habit of answering my own questions, but I give props to @jpemberthy and @Austin Taylor for pointing me in the right direction.  First (and this is cosmetic), I added this to my User model:

```
class User
  ...
  def self.create_guest
    self.new
  end

  def guest?
    uninitialized?
  end
end
```

and cleaned up my Abilities model accordingly:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.create_guest
    if (user.admin?)
      <admin abilities here>
    elsif (user.guest?)
      <guest abilities here>
    else
      <regular user abilities here>
    end
  end
end
```

But the real fix was in my RSpec tests.  Since User has validations on email and password fields, my original code of:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = User.create
end
```

was failing, thus creating an uninitialized `@user`.  Since the :id field was nil, the Ability clause:

```
can(:manage, User, :id => user.id)
```

was succeeding with a guest user because nil == nil (if that makes sense).  Adding the required fields to satisfy the User validations made (almost) everything work.

Moral: just as @jpemberthy suggested in his code, always include a test to make sure your user objects have the privileges that they are supposed to!  (I still have another question regarding CanCan, hopefully less boneheaded than this one, appearing in a StackOverflow topic near you...)

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use `#create!` rather than `#create` in tests. This will raise an error if validations fail, making it easier to track down problems. Or better yet, use a fixtures gem like machinist or factory_girl.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to work:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new           # create guest user if needed
    if (user.has_role?(:admin))
      can(:manage, :all)
    elsif user.persisted?
      can(:manage, User, :id => user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what the behavior is defined to be if you pass `:id => nil`, which is what happens in the guest case, but at any rate, if you don't want the guest to access the list view, you shouldn't call `can :manage, User` for that user at all.

In general, I find that assigning `user ||= User.new` to make the ability harder to reason about.

Comment: my error was in creating @user and @admin in the tests.  See my edits/comments in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, apparently this should work, but some refactoring would help you to find the issue:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'cancan/matchers'

describe Ability do
  before(:each) { @user = User.create }

  describe 'guest user' do
    before(:each) { @ability = Ability.new(nil) }
    subject { @ability } # take advantage of subject

    it "should not be an admin user" do
      @user.should_not be_admin
      @user.should be_guest
    end

    it "should_not show other user" do
      should_not be_able_to(:read, @user)
    end

    it "should_not create other user" do
      should_not be_able_to(:create, User)
    end

    it "should_not update other user" do
      should_not be_able_to(:update, @user)
    end

    it "should_not destroy other user" do
      should_not be_able_to(:destroy, @user)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that also I removed this example `@ability.should_not be_able_to(:read, User)`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Not to sound dense, but: how is refactoring supposed to help?  RSpec's `subject` feature is nice, but your example fails in exactly the same way that mine do.  What's more, I explicitly do NOT want a guest user (or any non-admin user) to be able to list all the other users (User.all in the model, UsersController#index in the controller) -- I'm not sure why you removed that test.

Comment: I don't know who voted you down, but despite my previous comment, I'm voting you back up: your test for "it should not be an admin user" was part of my 'aha! i'm an idiot' realization.  See further comments under the original post...

Comment: @fearless_fool yup that's why I added that example, I had the felling User.create for some reason wasn't creating `guest` users by default :P.

Comment: @jpemberty: well, good intuition, but ultimately, the problem was that User.create **was** creating guest users, even when I meant to be creating administrators and regular users! :)